# Incoming request from PayU is blocking? .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, payu

In the beginning sorry for language mistakes.
I try implement PayU Payment With [this](https://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html) documentation.
I stopped at the moment where PayU Api send notification with confirmation successful or unsuccessful payment.
My controller doesn't get request from they api but get request from my postman.
I don`t know if this is important but I don't see they request in fiddler.

I Use .net core 3.1
There is my controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("notify")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> notify([FromBody]Rootobject income)
    {
       ...code
    }
```

I turned off my firewall and I don't know what the problem is.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you specify the notifyUrl with your endpoint correctly, but not get notification(s)?

Comment: Exactly, I send two prop, notifyUrl and continueUrl. continueUrl - works, notifyUrl  - don`t work